# Pubnub : Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: pubnub

What is this error and how do I resolve it?
It has been happening a lot recently.

```
[Error: 128-0] : Unable to get Response Code. Please contact support with error details. : http://pubsub-1.pubnub.com/subscribe/sub-c-7debcf5c-7a22-11e5-92ab-8b238450f091/melloto_hub_registration_hub_pub%2Cmelloto_user_registration_user_pub/0/14615102362831327?uuid=b38c9036-b9ce-4dd1-b9b9-3f6f8d34859c&pnsdk=Java%2F3.7.5 : java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
ERROR on channel HUB_1_sub-pnpres : [Error: 128-0] : Unable to get Response Code. Please contact support with error details. : http://pubsub-1.pubnub.com/subscribe/sub-c-7debcf5c-7a22-11e5-92ab-8b238450f091/HUB_1_sub-pnpres/0/14615098338448243?uuid=d316c310-cb93-432a-9a4f-574d8c4d811e&pnsdk=Java%2F3.7.5 : java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

*Note: The Sub key value here has been changed from its actual so I could post in a public forum*

Comment: can you send your real sub-key to PubNub Support

Comment: Sure @CraigConover

Comment: @searcotjabali the order of key to pass to Pubnub function is (Publish key, Subscriber Key). I think u passed reverse